# Is it possible to step through Roslyn code in a Visual Studio package

Tags: visual-studio-2019, roslyn, vspackage

I am using Roslyn in my Visual Studio Package. I have the [source code of Roslyn from github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn), so I can look at the internal workings.

Is there any way that I can get debug information and step into the Roslyn code when debugging my Visual Studio Package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try using [SourceLink](https://github.com/dotnet/sourcelink). it's included in Visual Studio, and you can enable it by following [this guide](https://aaronstannard.com/visual-studio-sourcelink-setup/).

Comment: This will  also work for any Nuget package that has symbols published in nuget.org or private feeds